# Encoding arguments for UniswapV3 trade function

Tags: uniswap, abiencoderv2, hex

I am trying to encode arguments to call the [UniswapV3ExchangeAdapter](https://etherscan.io/address/0xcC327D928925584AB00Fe83646719dEAE15E0424#code) through the Set-Protocol [TradeModule](https://etherscan.io/address/0x90f765f63e7dc5ae97d6c576bf693fb6af41c129#code). The UniswapV3ExchangeAdapter has a function which is called `generateDataParam` that given hops and fees returns the data needed to make the trade calls. I am calling it with:

```
  '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2',
  '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48'
] [ '500' ]
```

which is returning:

`0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc20001f4a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48`
However when I try to feed this into the `tradeModuleInstance.methods.trade` I get the error `param.substring is not a function` which is basically a revert or a failure to encode parameters.

The code which I'm using to call the `trade` function:

```
const tx = tradeModuleInstance.methods.trade(
    setTokenAddress,
    process.env.uniswapAdapter,
    sourceToken,
    sourceUnits,
    targetToken,
    minTargetUnits,
    // web3.utils.hexToBytes(generatedParams), tried this to to no avail
    Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(generatedParams.slice(2), 'hex')),
  )
```

The full parameters I'm calling the `trade` function with are (set address redacted):

```
0x[redacted] 
UniswapV3ExchangeAdapter 
0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2 
1000000000 
0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48 
200000 
[
  192,  42, 170, 57, 178,  35, 254, 141,  10,
   14,  92,  79, 39, 234, 217,   8,  60, 117,
  108, 194,   0,  1, 244, 160, 184, 105, 145,
  198,  33, 139, 54, 193, 209, 157,  74,  46,
  158, 176, 206, 54,   6, 235,  72
]
```

I am not sure how to pass this `data` argument from the `generatedParams` so that UniswapV3 can work with it. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by using directly the `generatedParams` parameter into the `trade` function without any encoding and it worked.